# Spring Websocket: How intercept a message sent by SimpMessagingTemplate through any either convertAndSend or convertAndSendToUser methods?

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

For `Spring Websocket`

I have the following and works fine:

```
private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

...

@Scheduled(cron="some expression")
public void sendNotification() {
    logger.info("sendNotification ...");

    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(
            "/topic/something", 
            new Notification(...));

    logger.info("... sendNotification");
}
```

The code works fine. All the clients subscribed to that `Topic`, (I am working with `ActiveMQ`) are able to see the message(s) sent.

A custom class

```
@Component
class MessageChannelInterceptorAdapter extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {
```

With all the methods `@Override` was created to interception purposes.

This `MessageChannelInterceptorAdapter` class is registered about infrastructure as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("messageChannelInterceptorAdapter")
    private ChannelInterceptorAdapter messageChannelInterceptorAdapter;

...

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(messageChannelInterceptorAdapter);
        WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.super.configureClientInboundChannel(registration);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(messageChannelInterceptorAdapter);
        WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.super.configureClientOutboundChannel(registration);
    }

...
```

Even when the app works fine. The messages sent through `SimpMessagingTemplate` never are intercepted by `MessageChannelInterceptorAdapter`.

**Note:** the `MessageChannelInterceptorAdapter` class works fine to intercept `Stomp` events but again not for `SimpMessagingTemplate`

Thus: How intercept any message sent by `SimpMessagingTemplate` through either `convertAndSend` or `convertAndSendToUser` methods?

What is missing? missing configuration about infrastructure or create other class extending a specific Spring class.

Comment: Ever make any progress?

Comment: @Jeef Yes, about `SimpMessagingTemplate`, the interceptor only works how is expected **only** when exists a client _listening_ the `Destination`. Because it is `Topic` in my case and there is no consumers, the message is sent but is lost and the interceptor never works.

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I can tell there isn't an easy way to do this.  I had a situation where I was calling the template directly (like you).  When I migrated to use an external STOMP broker I found out suddenly some of my calls were no longer valid:

`/topic/sddf/traffic` is no longer a valid destination when you use Rabbit

I looked into writing my own version of the class `SimpMessagingTemplate` which became too difficultly - so instead I had to manually change all the calls.

***My example is in Kotlin not Java***

My solution was to go with this class:

```
@Component
@Configurable
class MessagingTemplateWrapper{

    var template: SimpMessagingTemplate = ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean(SimpMessagingTemplate::class.java)
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BridgeDataListener::class.java)

    fun convertAndSend(dest: String, data: Any) {

        val rabbitDestination = dest.substring(0,11) + dest.substring(11).replace("/",".")
        template.convertAndSend(rabbitDestination, data)
    }
}
```

And anywhere where I was using the template I did this:

```
//    var template: SimpMessagingTemplate = ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean(SimpMessagingTemplate::class.java)
var template: MessagingTemplateWrapper = ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean(MessagingTemplateWrapper::class.java)
```

So I just had a wrapper to do (maybe) what you wanted.

I don't love the solution - but it does work.